# Graph Coloring with greedy algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, greedy, graph-coloring

I'm trying to color a graph on Java.

For example, I have a graph like this:

[image: An example]

Now I want to fill the verticles with color 0 (red), 1 (blue), or 2 (green). One of possible result would be:

```
Vertex 1 ---> Color 1 
Vertex 2 ---> Color 1 
Vertex 3 ---> Color 2
Vertex 4 ---> Color 0
Vertex 5 ---> Color 0
Vertex 6 ---> Color 2
```

Here's my code with a method I found that uses greedy algorithm to color the vertex

```
public class Graph {
            int V;
            int[] verticleColor;
            boolean[] colorAvailable;
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > adjList;

            Graph(int v) { 
                V = v; 
                adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> >(V); 
                for (int i = 0; i < V+1; i++) {
                    adjList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); 
                }
            } 

            public void add(int x, int y) { 
                adjList.get(x).add(y); 
                adjList.get(y).add(x); 
            }

            public void colorTheVerticle() {
                 verticleColor = new int[V]; 

                for (int a = 0; a < verticleColor.length; a++) {
                    if (a == 0) {
                        verticleColor[a] = 0;
                    } else {
                        verticleColor[a] = -1;
                    }
                }

                colorAvailable = new boolean[V]; 
                for (int b = 0; b < colorAvailable.length; b++) {
                    colorAvailable[b] = true;
                }



                for (int c = 1; c < V; c++) {
                    Iterator<Integer> it = adjList.get(c).iterator() ; 
                    while (it.hasNext()) { 
                        int i = it.next();
                        if (verticleColor[i-1] != -1)  {
                            colorAvailable[verticleColor[i]] = false; 
                        }
                    } 


                    int color; 
                    for (color = 0; color < V; color++){ 
                        if (colorAvailable[color]) {
                            break; 
                        }
                    } 

                    verticleColor[c] = color; 

                    for (int d = 0; d <  colorAvailable.length; d++) {
                        colorAvailable[d] = true;
                    } 
                } 

                for (int u = 1; u < V+1; u++) {
                    System.out.println("Vertex " + u + " ---> Color " + verticleColor[u-1]);
                }
}
```

The problem is, I get different result than I hoped for, which is:

```
Vertex 1 ---> Color 0
Vertex 2 ---> Color 0
Vertex 3 ---> Color 0
Vertex 4 ---> Color 1
Vertex 5 ---> Color 0
Vertex 6 ---> Color 2
```

Also, changing a bit of the method would get me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

A little explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not working with Java at the moment but I can understand the code.

The code **depends on 2 facts**:

1. For a graph of n vertices at most n colors will have to be used.
2. Loop through each vertex and assign an available color based on available colors list not used on colors of adjacent vertices.

The above facts suggest the greedy algorithm used which at most will use n colors but often less than n colors (unless every vertex is connected to each other) although not optimal in general.

Analysing the method that computes the coloring we have:

**initialisation steps**

```
verticleColor = new int[V]; // initialise the colors assigned to each vertex to a list

for (int a = 0; a < verticleColor.length; a++) {
   if (a == 0) {
      verticleColor[a] = 0; // we can assign the first color to first vertex, no problem
   } else {
      verticleColor[a] = -1; // else for rest vertices, no assigned color yet
   }
}


colorAvailable = new boolean[V]; // initialise a list of available colors to assign to vertices, at most n
for (int b = 0; b < colorAvailable.length; b++) {
   colorAvailable[b] = true; // initially all colors are available for assignment
}
```

**main computation loop**

```
            for (int c = 1; c < V; c++) { // for all vertices, except first
                Iterator<Integer> it = adjList.get(c).iterator() ; // get iterator that loops through current vertex's adjacent vertices
                while (it.hasNext()) { 
                    int i = it.next(); // adjacent vertex
                    if (verticleColor[i-1] != -1)  { // if assigned color
                        colorAvailable[verticleColor[i]] = false; // this color is not available anymore
                    }
                } 


                int color; 
                for (color = 0; color < V; color++){ // loop through all colors
                    if (colorAvailable[color]) {
                        break; // find first available color, we can always find an available color since we have at most n possible colors
                    }
                } 
                /* effectively availableColors list holds the available and
                 used colors for each vertex and its adjacent/connected 
                 vertices, but we do not need to store multiple 
                 availableColors for each vertex, we can re-use same, no problem
                */
                verticleColor[c] = color; // color the vertex with this color

                // for next round, all colors are again available
                for (int d = 0; d <  colorAvailable.length; d++) {
                    colorAvailable[d] = true; // available color
                } 
            }
```